# bootstrap 4 chrome animation lag accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, bootstrap-4

As the title says, the animation for accordion, when using it, lags incredibly. Does not persist on Edge or Firefox, or even Android Samsung Browser seems to be fine handling it. But in Chrome it lags immensely.

There is no point in showing my personal code due to the fact I literally tried simply copy-pasting the code from [Accordion Example on Bootstrap 4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example) and it works just as bad.

For some odd reason, not using accordion, but instead using this [multiple-targets code from the example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#multiple-targets) works fine.

EDIT: Before submitting this, decided to fiddle around on my other part of website and turns out that the animation is very laggy in Chrome when it shifts the page down (when displaying new content the page shifts down). Without shifting it down, when I put Chrome tab in 25% of original size, it worked flawlessly. Is there any way this can be remedied?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but there's a huge gap between the js-animation and the css-animation. Since bootstrap uses a js-animation, it will be a lot slower and laggy. So if you're going to use bootstrap and its animation, you'll be suffering more on performance. Meanwhile, you could use other js library that supports animation like GSAP(GreenSock Animation Platform), etc.. Or, you could use CSS animation since it is the most-acclaimed solution in-terms of animation.

Comment: How is it the most acclaimed? Genuinely curious, but really might as well go with css animation in this case

Comment: You might to read forums relating to this topic. And most of them (with proofs) shows that css animation is better than js animation.